# Sitecore Form with multiple page displaying the field values in consequent page entered in previous page

Tags: sitecore-forms, validation

I would like to know if the following situation is possible to handle with Sitecore Forms.

**Situation:** The first page contains a form, the user clicks a button under the form and it is validated, but not submitted. The user is then taken to a second page(Review page to review the values entered in first page) where they can see all the values they have added and can review the data. At this stage the user is shown two buttons:

- **Edit button** that takes the user to previous page to let the user edit values.
- **Submit button** that submits the data.

Kindly suggest if this is possible using sitecore Forms.

Comment: Did you check the wizard like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY3BSCSiLA8

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is :Yes.

The long story would be that I assume that you are about to create a `multipage form`, right?

If you want to create a long form with `multiple` sections, you can use the `Page element` to break the form up into multiple pages and make it more user-friendly.

`Multipage forms` also enable you to create a `conditional scenario`.

There is a detailed post similar to the scenario at [Create an smart Sitecore Form with different pages based on conditions](https://jesuissitecore.com/2020/04/14/create-an-smart-sitecore-form-with-different-pages-based-on-conditions/)

Also if you wanna futher explore that, you can try [Sitecore Forms Conditional](https://www.oshyn.com/blog/sitecore-forms-conditional-validation-p1)

---

To achieve the field values across pages, you can try the following ways.

- Use Session state

1.on page 1 post and save the fields value in Session state.

2.when in Page 2, try get the values from Session and display that.

- Use a hidden field

1.Add a hidden field on page 1 and store the values you like to pass .

2.Bind the field value to page 2 and diplay it as you like.

Also you can use query string parameters if the value is not sensitive.

Comment: Hi Alexander, Thanks for the response. The requirement is in 2nd page of the form to display the values that are entered in the first page. Is that possible. I am unable to find if this kind of feature is covered in the above articles shared by you.

Comment: @ChristopherRaja yes, there are a few ways to achieve that. you can use session or hidden field to get the field values you entered in the 1st page. I posted and edit the answers above, please have a check and see if it helps.